# Vírgulas em ''além de''

Tags: sintaxe, vírgula

Gostaria de saber se a expressão **além de** é intercalada por vírgulas e qual é a sua função sintática.

Colocando em contexto:

> 1) Gosto de gatos além de cachorros
>
> 2) Gosto de gatos, além de cachorros

Qual das duas formas seria a correta?

Comment: Há vírgula, a qual separa expressões de natureza explicativa: Gosto de gatos, além de cachorros. http://www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/113599

Answer (score 1):

1) Diz que você gosta de gatos espacialmente além de cachorros, gatos atrás de cachorros de seu ponto de vista.
2) Diz que você gosta de gatos, não apenas, porém em adição a gostar de cachorros. Em totalidade, seria "Gosto de gatos, além de gostar de cachorros", porém a forma resumida é melhor, convenhamos.
A função sintática é locução adverbial.

A propósito, soa mais natural o uso de "Além de cachorros, gosto de gatos.", pois a informação de retomada de 'Além de cachorros' estaria mais próxima estruturalmente do lugar do texto em que você disse que gosta de cachorro (antes no texto, isto é); além de que é mais comum formular-se dessa maneira.